# Reordering buttons in UI as the size is adjusted

Tags: visual-c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm developing a UI using wxWidgets. I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express.

My UI consists of 7 vertical grids and 1 horizontal grid which envelopes this 7. In each of these 7 grids, I have 2 or 3 bitmap buttons which are relatively ordered according to each other and neighbor grid boundaries. I set the main horizontal grid as sizer to the panel.

I want that these 7 grids always take place in the "middle" of my panel; which means: With every size adjustment, their coordinates should be recalculated and buttons should move to their newly calculated locations.

Is it possible to do this size adjustment with wxWidgets? I checked on the documentation and samples, but I couldn't find a simple example for my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a resize event handler which recalculates the positions of the buttons and moves them to their new locations.

```
void myWindow::OnResize( wxSizeEvent& event )
{
    wxSize sz = event.GetSize();
    // calculate new positions
    ...
    // move buttons to new locations
    myButton->Move( x, y )'
}
```